# Convergence of a probability that at least some events occurs

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

For positive integer $S \geq 1$ and a probability $0<p<1$ of occurring an event,
We want to show that
$ \mathop{ \lim } \limits_{N \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1- \sum_{i=0}^{S-1} \binom{N}{i} p^{i}\left( 1-p \right)^{N-i} \right) \rightarrow 1.$
($S$ is finite value.)

Actually, we are not sure that the above probability converges to one or not.
We think that 
$\mathop{ \lim } \limits_{N \rightarrow \infty} \binom{N}{i} p^{i}\left( 1-p \right)^{N-i} \rightarrow 0$ for finite value $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

It just require you to use the Stirling formula.

Since each summand is positive, the statement is true if and only if all of the summand converge to 0. So it is equivalent to prove your second statement.

Note

$$ \begin{align*} \binom {N} {i} p^i (1-p)^{N-i} 
&= \frac {N!} {(N-i)!i!} p^i(1-p)^{N-i} \\
&= \frac {p^i} {i!} \frac {N!} {\sqrt{2\pi N} (\frac {N} {e})^{N}}
\frac {\sqrt{2\pi (N-i)} (\frac {N-i} {e})^{N-i}} {(N-i)!}
\sqrt {\frac {N} {N-i}} \frac {N^i} {e^i} 
\left(1 + \frac {i} {N-i} \right)^{N-i} (1 - p)^{N-i}
\end{align*}$$

Therefore
$$ \lim_{N\to\infty}\binom {N} {i} p^i (1-p)^{N-i} = \frac {p^i} {i!} \lim_{N\to\infty} N^i (1-p)^{N-i} $$

By applying L'hopital rule $i$ times,

$$ \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac {N^i} {(1 - p)^{-N+i}} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac {i!} {(-1)^i[\ln(1-p)]^i(1 - p)^{-N+i}} = 0$$

which complete the proof.